# I'm getting this error: "Shape of passed values is (55, 93315), indices imply (68, 93315)" when applying the Imputer

Tags: pandas, dataframe, imputation

Here is my code

`
        from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer

```
    imp = Imputer(strategy='median')
    imputed_df = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df1), columns=df1.columns)`
```

The error message: "Shape of passed values is (55, 93315), indices imply (68, 93315)"

The shape of df1 is: (93315, 68)
but the shape of imputed_df is: (93315, 55)
Any explanation??

Answer (score 1):

**Check for columns in the df1, there might be having columns with all NaN values or missing values**.

From Documentation:

> Columns which only contained missing values at :meth:`fit` are discarded
>       upon :meth:`transform` if strategy is not "constant".

The error is thrown by the pandas dataframe constructor, implying mismatch, as the fit_transform of sklearn imputer drops the columns containing all missing values. The documentation states the same. Read more here [https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html")!
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/fd237278e/sklearn/impute/_base.py#L205